# Hausdorff dimension of Apollonian circle packing, 1.305686729, 1.305688 or yet something else?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, hausdorff-dimension, circle-packing

I am interested in the Hausdorff dimension of the Apollonian circle packing.
There seem to be two numerical calculations of the value:

```
1.305686729(10)
```

from [P.B Thomas and D.Dhar, *The Hausdorf*[sic!] *dimension of the Apollonian packing of circles* Journal of Physics A: Mathematical and General, Volume 27, Number 7, April 1994](http://dx.doi.org/10.1088/0305-4470/27/7/007)

and later from Curt McMullen (he does not cite Thomas and Dhar):

```
1.305688
```

[McMullen, Curtis T. *Hausdorff dimension and conformal dynamics. III. Computation of dimension.* Amer. J. Math. 120, no. 4, 691–721. 1998](https://dash.harvard.edu/handle/1/3445973)

His algorithm is also explained in Section 5.5 on page 156 in "Indra's Pearls" by Mumford and Series (beware of some typos on that page!).

It is somewhat unsatisfying to have two contradicting numerical approximations. The OEIS gives 1.3056867 and does not cite McMullen, see [A052483](http://oeis.org/A052483) (as of today).

With modern computers it might be worthwhile trying to settle this question. Curt McMullen has a C-program on his website that can calculate the Hausdorff dimension, that I am interested in:
hdim.tar on
http://abel.math.harvard.edu/~ctm/programs/index.html

Running

```
./hdim -a -e .00005
```

gives as output

```
Apollonian gasket


Epsilon   Dimension   Cover  Matrix Steps
5.00e-05 1.305687542911558287346746 76
```

So I guess after 76 steps (and about a week of computation time) we get
1.30568754291
as an numerical approximation.

- Does this mean that actually the first few digits are
  1.305687?
- What are the correct first few decimal digits of this number?
- What are the best proven exact bounds and what are the most promising numerical experiments to get a good approximation?

Comment: Doesn't that calculation mean the answer is within .00005 of the correct value?  Both of the values cited above satisfy this.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar "-e" is the pruning epsilon. From the README:
"-e:  prunes Markov partition by stopping subdivision of
     blocks of size less than epsilon."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems in the meantime, there are new results:

[Bai, Zai-Qiao; Finch, Steven R. *Precise calculation of Hausdorff dimension of Apollonian gasket*. Fractals 26 (2018), no. 4, 9 pp.](https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/pdf/10.1142/S0218348X18500500)
claims a better approximation is

$$1.3056867280498771846459862068510\dots$$

Answer (score 10):

[Roberto De Leo, *A conjecture on the Hausdorff dimension of attractors of real self-projective Iterated Function Systems*, Experimental Mathematics **24**, 270 (2015)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/268225916), [doi:10.1080/10586458.2014.987884](http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/10586458.2014.987884), using a different method, confirms the figure by Thomas & Dhar (at least the digits 1.3056867) and suggests an error in McMullen's result.

I will add this reference to the OEIS.